# TeamFoundationServerUnauthorizedException: TF30063 but access via Visual Studio works fine and TFS web works fine too

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I have downloaded and setup [SpruceSite](http://spruce.codeplex.com/). However, when I launch the site I get the following error

```
TF30063: You are not authorized to access http://<tfsservername>:8080/tfs/
```

However, I can access `http://<tfsservername>:8080/tfs` and it works perfectly fine. It redirects me to `http://<tfsservername>:8080/tfs/web/` without any issues.

Also, my user is both Contributors / Project Administrators for this project.

Is there any other permissions issue that I need to be granted with in order to be able to use this?

What I have tried so far -

Based on [this](http://blog.floatingant.com/2012/10/tfs30063you-are-not-authorized-to-access.html), tried to update the web.config to set it to the specific project collection, but even then it did not work. It came up with the same error.

Comment: Does the site use impersonation? If not then it will be running under the indentity of the web sites application pool. If thats the case you will need to give the identity account permissions to access TFS.

Comment: @JamesReed The site does use impersonation (assuming that from web.config entry which says `<identity impersonate="true" />` and it is running from my machine.